# Regular expression for a redirect

Tags: php, regex, redirect, http-redirect

I'm trying to write a regular expression for a redirect and not having any luck. In this example, an old URL might exist like this:

> example.com/about-us/Default.asp
>
> example.com/the-team/Default.asp

Which I want to redirect to:

> example.com/about-us/
>
> example.com/the-team/

I've come up with this:

```
/(\d*)/Default.asp
```

Which doesn't work...

I've also tried this:

```
/(\d*)/Default\.asp
```

As I thought there might be a problem with not having an escape char for the '.', still no luck. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you threw `/(\d*)/` in there? `\d` matches digits. Just `/Default\.asp$` would probably work, anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working thanks to what minitech pointed out:

```
/(.*)/Default.asp$
```

worked a treat! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you only need to remove the "Default.asp", you only have to search for that. The regex would look something like this

```
/Default\.asp/
```

The dot being escaped since the dot is a special character.

If you're using php, you can do a simple preg_replace

```
preg_replace('/Default\.asp/', '', 'example.com/about-us/Default.asp');
```

Comment: I agree, that would be more efficient than using a regex.